# Cassandra Leveled Compaction vs TimeWindowCompactionStrategy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

The idea behind TimeWindowCompactionStrategy is each SSTable has records from only a particular time window, instead of records from different time windows getting mixed with each other.

Doesn't Leveled Compaction result in something similar? SSTables are compacted with other SSTables from the same level, which are all from the same time window. (aka SSTables at higher levels are always older). This looks very similar to DateTieredCompactionStrategy, except that  the SSTable size is  determined by max size in MBs instead of a time window.

Answer (score 1):

LeveledCS is grouping SSTables by size in a multilevel structure, while TimeWindowCS is making same-interval SSTables (thus it's a single level structure) and has limitations on number of buckets so tables with TWCS requires TTL for all rows.

You are correct about difference between DTCS and LCS.

P.S. I recommend to watch the [slides from presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/JeffJirsa1/cassandra-summit-2015-real-world-dtcs-for-operators) by the author of TWCS to get the reasoning behind it.